# C program using array char* crash

Tags: c, crash

I want to build a program that allow to insert name and print out. But the program crash whenever it begin.

This is my main class:

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int* n = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    char listStudent[100][31];
    char* name = (char*) malloc(31);
    int id;
    *n = 0;
    addStudent("John ABC", listStudent, n);
    addStudent("David Davinci", listStudent, n);
}
```

And some function to call

```
void addStudent(char name[31], char listName[][31], int *pn) {
    int id;
    id = findName(name, listName, *pn);
    if(id < 0) {
        addName(name, listName, *pn);
        printf("%s has been added", name);
    } else
        printf("The student was exist\n");
}


int findName(char name[31], char listName[][31], int n) {
    int found = FALSE;
    int i, id;
    id = -1;
    for(i = 0; i < n && (!found); i++)
        if(stricmp(listName[i], name) == 0) {
            found = TRUE;
            id = i;
        }

    return id;
}

void addName(char str[31], char listName[][31], int* pn) {
    if(*pn > 100)
        printf("List is full !!");
    else
        strcpy(listName[(*pn)++],str);  
}
```

Thanks advance for your help!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not crashing.
Now its up to you to make it work as you wish.

```
void addStudent(char* name, char listName[][31], int* n) {
    int id;
   // printf("%s", name);
    id = findName(name, listName, n);
    if(id < 0) {
        addName(name, listName, n);
        printf("%s has been added\n", name);
    } else
        printf("The student already exists\n");
}


int findName(char* name, char listName[][31], int n) {
    int found = 0;
    int i, id;
    id = -1;
    for(i = 0; i<100 && &(n) < 100 &&(!found); i++)
        if(strcmp(listName[i], name) == 0) {
            found = 1;
            id = i;
        }
    return id;
}

void addName(char str[31], char listName[][31], int* pn) {
    if(pn > 100)
        printf("List is full !!\n");
    else
        strcpy(listName[(*pn)++],str);
}


void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n = 0;
    char listStudent[100][31];
    int id;
    addStudent("John ABC", listStudent, &(n));
    addStudent("David Davinci", listStudent, &(n));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have detected a problem.

Comment: What problem ? ask if you don't understand and I will explain the minor changes. I thought they were obvious.

Comment: This is my fault. In addStudent function. I call addName(name, listName, *pn); This *pn parameter is cause.